# CSS: Full-screen fluid layout with 2 columns

Tags: css, layout, fullscreen

I'm searching for a full-screen (height: 100%, width: 100%, so no scroll bars) fluid layout with a header and 2 colomns, the left one for the navigation menu and the right one for the content. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds great, now can we see your code please?

Comment: You can use Bootstrap, by visiting this http://bootswatch.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7zjp/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='header'>Header</div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Menu</div>
        <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.header {
    display:table-header-group;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Is it consistent with CSS W3C standard? I've never heard of "display:table-cell" before. Thanks

Comment: How am I supposed to resize the height of the header and the width od the cells? Thank you